# Why inline and inline-block have different height with the same text content

Tags: html, css

In the below code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<span class="d-inline" style="border: 1px red solid; padding: 3px 0"><span>asbbb</span></span>
  <span class="d-inline-block ml-2" style="border: 1px blue solid; padding: 3px 0;"><span>inline-block</span></span>
<div>
  
<br/>
  <span class="d-inline badge" style="border: 1px red solid"><span>asbbb</span></span>
  <span class="d-inline-block badge ml-2" style="border: 1px blue solid"><span>inline-block</span></span>
</div>
```

I created two lines to show the height difference between `inline` and `inline-block` in the same line.

The first line shows `inline-block` is a little bit higher than `inline` sibling.

In the second line, I added bootstrap class `badge` to both, and it shows `inline` element is a bit higher than its `inline-block` sibling.

For both lines, I can see from the DevTools that the inner `span` has the same height, but they end up having different height with their parent container.

I wonder how the height of the two `display` types are calculated?

Comment: Did you read the spec?

Comment: @connexo Yes I read the one on MDN, but couldn't get where it's defined. Appreciate if you could point out another place with more details : )

Comment: @JunlongWang The height of inner `span` will be same because of the same size. But the outer `span` having the classes have little different heights. Also, check my answer if you want to know how height and width are affected in each of them.

Comment: While other answers are appreciated, but they are more of explaining the difference between `inline` and `inline-block`, which is not in the scope of my question. I think @temani has given the most relevant answer that helps my understanding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is related to how `line-height` works and how the height of each element is calculated.

Let's start with a trivial example to highlight the effect of `line-height`

```css
span {
  border:1px solid red;
  padding:5px;
  line-height:50px;
}
```

```html
<span>some text</span> <span style="display:inline-block">some text</span>
```

Note how in the second case the height is getting bigger but not in the first case.

> On a block container element whose content is composed of inline-level elements, `line-height` **specifies the minimal height** of line boxes within the element.<sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height)</sup>

The above apply to the `inline-block` element and it's clear that line-height will increase the height. To be more accurate, the height of the inline-block is the sum of its line boxes height and in your case we have only one defined with the `line-height` value.

> On a non-replaced inline element, 'line-height' specifies the height that is used in the calculation of the line box height.

The above apply to the `inline` element where the line-height won't increase the height but will only increase the height of the line box where it belong

```css
span {
  border:1px solid red;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<div style="border:1px solid blue;">
<span>some text</span>
</div>
<br>
<div style="border:1px solid blue;">
<span style="line-height:100px;">some text</span>
</div>
```

---

To identify the height of an inline element, it's a bit tricky because it depends on the font properties and is covered in another part of the specification:

> The 'height' property does not apply. **The height of the content area should be based on the font**, but this specification does not specify how. A UA may, e.g., use the em-box or the maximum ascender and descender of the font. (The latter would ensure that glyphs with parts above or below the em-box still fall within the content area, but leads to differently sized boxes for different fonts; the former would ensure authors can control background styling relative to the 'line-height', but leads to glyphs painting outside their content area.) <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced)</sup>

---

Considering this we can identify the height of each one.

For the first line:

1. the inline-block is inherting `line-height:1.5` and `font-size:1rem` so we will get a line-box height equal to `1.5x1rem = 1.5x16px = 24px`. we add the padding/border to get the `32px`
2. the inline element is getting a content height for the font equal to `21px`<sup>1</sup> and adding padding/border we get `29px`

For the second line the `.badge` will apply `font-size: 75%;line-height: 1;` so

1. the inline-block will get `1x1remx0.75 = 0.75x16px = 12px` and with border/padding we get `20px`
2. the inline element will logically have 75% of the previous content area so `0.75x21px = 15.75px` and with border/padding we get `23.75px ~ 24px`

---

<sup>1</sup>In order to identify how the content area is calculated you need to see how the font is designed and find some *complex* metrics.

below some a related questions that can help you:

[What determines the space between the highest and lowest letter and the top and bottom border of the element the letter's in?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61990176/8620333)

[How can I calculate the size of font when using different font-types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61839926/8620333)

---

Another related question around height calculation: [How to determine height of content-box of a block and inline element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61830546/8620333)

Comment: Hi @TemaniAfif. To me the bit that's missing is how height of the inline-block is formed from the line-height. That is, that the height is the sum of the heights of the stack of line-boxes that it contains, plus the padding and borders of the inline-block, which surround that stack.

Comment: @Alohci True, I considered one line box and went to fast on that part. Will update with more details, thanks.

Comment: While other answers are appreciated, but they are more of explaining the difference between `inline` and `inline-block`, which is not in the scope of my question. I think Temani has given the most relevant answer that helps my understanding.

Answer (score 2):

**Rule 1**: you cannot set `height` and `width` for `display: inline;` elements.

**Rule 2**: the `line-height` property does not work for `display: inline-block;` elements, It rather get's applied to it's child elements.

**In your 1st case:**
The `line-height: 1.5` property which is set on your `body` affects both of your span elements.
For the `inline` span even though the `line-height` is applied your element's height wont change due to **rule 1** above.
For the `inline-block` span it dosen't get applied to it, rather it is applied to its child element which is in your case another `span` element due to **rule 2**. Since the `line-height` gets applied to it's child element the height increases & because it's parent is an `inline-block` element the height is applied to it and thats why you see a little raise in the height.

**In your 2nd case:**
The bootstrap badge class already contains a `line-height: 1` property which overides your body's `line-height: 1.5` property.
For the `inline` span nothing affects because of the **rule 1**.
For the `inline-block` span however, instead of the body's `line-height: 1.5` the badge class `line-height: 1` gets applied to it's inner span element and therefore you see it's height smaller compared to the first case.

> **Note:** Although `inline` elements don't respect height & width, they do respect elements left & right padding property.

Comment: *the line-height property does not work for display: inline-block; elements, It rather get's applied to it's child elements.* --> it does. Line height apply to block container which is the case of inline-block (https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) but you should note that it's inherited so all the child elements will inherit it and here we follow the rule of inline elements

Comment: Thanks for your reply @dhruwlalan, I think the `line-height` applies to both `inline` and `inline-block` as it can be seen in the devtools. Also, there's no `height` specified on the two lines of example in my link, so I don't think `height` has things to do here.

Answer (score 0):

The major difference between **`inline`** and **`inline-block`** is that the latter allows to set a width and height on the element. Also, with `display: inline`, top and bottom margins & paddings are not respected, and with `display: inline-block` they are. The differe

### `display: inline`

```css
span.box {
  display: inline;  /* the default for span */
  width: 100px;
  height: 160px;
  padding: 18px;
  border: 3px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet <span class="box">Inline!</span> consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui,<span class="box">Inline again!</span> itaque sit incidunt totam harum ratione nulla. Labore quis eligendi aperiam laborum harum. Perferendis, laborum unde.
  Tenetur eveniet praesentium corporis perspiciatis?</p>
```

### `display: inline-block`

```css
span.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 160px;
  padding: 18px;
  border: 3px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet <span class="box">Inline-block!</span> consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui,<span class="box">Inline-block again!</span> itaque sit incidunt totam harum ratione nulla. Labore quis eligendi aperiam laborum harum. Perferendis, laborum unde.
  Tenetur eveniet praesentium corporis perspiciatis?</p>
```

Notice that how the height and width of `inline-block` are preserved.

Comment: Hi Shounak, thanks for answering. I do know these facts, but I think in my example, they are not specified `height` and both have the same property values except for `display`, which causes the height difference along with their parents.

Comment: @JunlongWang It is probably because of Bootstrap's default styling.

Comment: Well I have checked the default styling for `badge` class and it is not the reason behind. And it shouldn't be the reason since they both are the same tag and are applied with the same bootstrap styling class.