# Why is the content bigger than the divs?

Tags: html, css

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdqcLkoy/5/)

If you inspect the div with text, you will see that it is larger than the anchor container. The font size is 1rem, the top and bottom margins of the div are both 0.5rem, which adds up to 2rem, which is set as the height of the anchor. Why is it not the full height?

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1;
}
nav a {
  font-size: 2rem;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 4rem;
  padding: 0rem 0.5rem 0rem 0.5rem;
  border: white 1px solid;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: black;
  transition: background-color 0.5s, color 0.5s, height 0.5s;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
}
nav a div {
  margin: 1rem 0rem 1rem 0rem;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a>
    <div>text</div>
  </a>
</nav>
```

Comment: no it's not bigger !!! ancore size is `42*34` and the div size is `24*18`

Comment: i could get it to 'line up' when i changed the nav a height to 2.1rem

Comment: I don't see any default values that would be interfering...https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp

Comment: fiddle sometimes gives me grief when using flex.. I get the Same 'not full height' behavior in vs code

Comment: when you toggle the height (formerly 2rem) it was jumping from 34 to 36.  36 is the correctness we want. is this ocd css?

Comment: you can get it to line up in that specific case. I was wondering why this happens at all?

Comment: Agreed. it's a strange one! I bet Una Kravets would have an answer.

Comment: I switched height to line height and it lines up

Answer (score 2):

The problem boils down to line height.

You have set your `<a>` to have height of `4rem`, with `2rem` font size and top and bottom margins of `1rem` each. Obviously 2 + 1 + 1 adds up to 4, so that seems like it should work, but your font size is multiplied by your line height in order to come up with the total height it actually occupies.

Given that the browser's default line height is greater than 1, and the default suggested line height for most every font is greater than 1, that almost always means you will end up with overflow like this.

#### Possible solutions

1. Set `line-height: 1` on your `<a>`. If you know the text in the `<a>` won't wrap anyway, this will be fine, and you'll have no problems.

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1;
}
nav a {
  font-size: 2rem;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 4rem;
  padding: 0rem 0.5rem 0rem 0.5rem;
  border: white 1px solid;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: black;
  transition: background-color 0.5s, color 0.5s, height 0.5s;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  line-height: 1; /* add this */
}
nav a div {
  margin: 1rem 0rem 1rem 0rem;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a>
    <div>text</div>
  </a>
</nav>
```

2. Don't set an explicit height on `<a>`. Instead, let the height just be derived from the font size and line height. In order to keep the background color behind the whole height of the text, change its margin to padding. (In this case, take the padding you already have and add margin to it to get the new total number.) This approach is preferable if you think the text inside your link may wrap, because then you will actually want a readable line height so the lines don't squish together too much.

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1;
}
nav a {
  font-size: 2rem;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* height: 4rem; */
  padding: 1rem 0.5rem 1rem 0.5rem; /* <-- modified */
  border: white 1px solid;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: black;
  transition: background-color 0.5s, color 0.5s, height 0.5s;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
}
/* nav a div {
  margin: 1rem 0rem 1rem 0rem;
} */
```

```html
<nav>
  <a>
    <div>text</div>
  </a>
</nav>
```

Comment: it's more about the defaut value of line-height which is around 1.2 so 1.2x2rem + margin is bigger than 4rem

Comment: @TemaniAfif Revisiting this today, I can see you are right. The whole blockified line boxes thing doesn't even apply here. I updated my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To get the *nav a div* element to respect its parent element's height, I added...

```
nav a {
    display: flex;
}
```

And to have it be vertically centered, I added the above code plus...

```
nav a div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    line-height: 2rem; /* preference */
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. Did you inspect with Dev tools? When I do, I still see the discrepancy.

Comment: My apologies. Please try out the updated code above.

Comment: To be clear, it looks nice. However, that actually made the discrepancy worse. To be fair, the op has updated the fiddle and its no longer the original values

Comment: This is definitely one those 'deep dive' css issues something Una Kravets would probably like to get in on

Comment: The additional code I've added works with the [original code](https://jsfiddle.net/mdqcLkoy/5/) but if you have a new fiddle link you want to send me, just let me know. :-)

Answer (score 1):

BradTheBluefish's answer gave me a hint.

It must be some weirdnes with rendering the font-size property. What I should have been using was line-height. For some reason those are not the same. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/89hLyqkn/11/)

```
nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1;
}
nav a {
  line-height: 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 2rem;
  padding: 0rem 0.5rem 0rem 0.5rem;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: black;
  transition: background-color 0.5s, color 0.5s, height 0.5s;
}
nav a div {
  padding: 0.5em 0rem 0.5rem 0rem;
}
```

Comment: related to understand how the height is really calculated: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61830546/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/65399231/8620333

Answer (score 0):

You should add property: **display: inline-block/block** to tag a set width/height for its (default tag a is **display: inline**)