# Why does changing font-size on a div change its height?

Tags: html, css

I've got a structure that looks roughly like this:

- div (has font-size)

  - span (also has font-size, contains text)

Now, I'd think that the 2nd div would tightly wrap around the span. Their height would depend only on the span's font-size. However, if the div has its own font-size, it seems to contain some extra space, on top of the span itself.

Why is that?

```css
.div {
  font-size: 25px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.span {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  font-size: 12px;
  /* The boxes are equal in size when this font-size is about 20px */
}
```

```html
<div class="div"><span class="span">there!</span></div>
```

[Codesandbox link.](https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-sky-smzkr?file=/index.html)

[image: .]

Comment: the label create an inline formatting context so having a big font-size will increase its height. IF you make the span a block element, you won't get this

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65399231/8620333